# this is undefined in controller (ember, 3.x)

Tags: ember.js, controller, this, undefined

Run into a problem with ember (v.3.x), and cannot figure out why. I did not find anything (that worked in my case) in the docs nor here.

So, here's the problem: this returns undefined in my controller inside the computed property (undefined.get('filter')). The rest of my function works, so I did not put it in here.

```
// in dic.js (controller):
export default Controller.extend({
  filter: '',
  filteredTerms: computed('filter', () => {
     const x = this.get('filter');
     // ...
}),
```

The corresponding input field:

```
// in dic.hbs
{{input value=filter}}
```

In my route I just return the model, which should be filtered by that function.

Comment: try model.filter

Comment: model.filter does not work. the filter value is coming from the input field, which has nothing to do with the model...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple: don't use an arrow function for the computed. This should work:

```
filteredTerms: computed('filter', function () {
  const x = this.get('filter');
  // ...
```

This is the fundamental difference between normal functions and arrow functions. Arrow functions dont have their own `this`-context. `this` inside an arrow function is always the same as outside. And well, outside in this case it literally outside the object, so the global context. So you get `window`/`undefined` depending if you're in strict mode or not.

So general rule:

- use an arrow function if you want access to the outer `this` or dont use `this` at all
- use a normal function when you want a `this`-context

Comment: thanks for your explanation! worked :) looks like i was blind for the obvious.